# linking two articles using an image

Tags: joomla3.0

I am trying to link an image within an article to another article but when clicked all I get is a larger version of the image opening top of page. Tried amending html img src, used JCE editor to create links, created a hidden menu item and copied syntax, all to no avail. Any ideas please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is this:

```html
<a href="http://www.cnn.com/"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
```

Just wrap your image in an anchor tag with it pointing to the site you want to go to.

Comment: Have tried but still links back to the image src and displays larger image

Comment: Sounds like the JCE is forcing your image into a display box that just makes it bigger.

Comment: Have tried other editors too and still the same problem. Is there a bug somewhere?

Comment: Not sure, it is pretty straight forward, it would be helpful to see your code to see whats happening. It could be several issues.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it would be straightforward. Have even tried an external http link and get the same result. Here's a snippet of code that I expected to work;  <p><a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk"><img src="images/images/readmore.png" alt="readmore" width="86" height="30" /></a></p>
<p><span style="font-size: 12pt;"></span></p>

Comment: Here's the code that I am using to link to an article;  <p><a href="index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=12:morespec&amp;catid=2:uncategorised&amp;Itemid=1151"><img src="images/images/readmore.png" alt="readmore" width="86" height="30" /></a></p>
<p><span style="font-size: 12pt;"></span></p>

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments and assistance to date. Found the problem - a plug-in (jhimage popup), was causing the grief. Many thanks